# Trouble-shooting slow-loading documents from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

a customer representative suggested that I try posting these questions here.

We spent some time monitoring issues with DocuSign loading slowly. While it was now slow every time, when it was slow it seemed to hang up on a particular point in the process.

Below is a screenshot of a trace we ran in the browser and note the element which took 52 seconds to load. When loading was slow, it seemed to hang on this particular element. Could you offer any reasons as to why it could sometimes take 52 seconds or more to load this part?

We also have some other questions:

1. There seems to be continuous font downloading (2 or 3 meg in size) throughout the process of loading the page. This occurs each time. Why is this and can it be avoided?
2. Why do we sometimes see Seattle as the connection site when most of the time is Chicago?
3. We noticed that DocuSign asks for permission to know our location. Does this location factor into where the document is downloaded from? Is the location also used in embedded signing processes?

Thank you for your assistance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without a bit more detail I am not entirely sure I can tell you why the page was loading so slow. Is this consistent? If so is it always the same document (perhaps template?) where you see this slowness?

As for your other three questions:

1. In doing my own test and decryption of the web traffic via fiddler I show the fonts being rendered for each individual tag and not the entire document. This is most likely due to each tag having it's own attributes that can be set (font included).
2. DocuSign data centers are in Seattle, Chicago and Dallas. All DocuSign traffic can come from any of these three data centers as the system synchronously exists in all three locations. More info can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/how-it-works/security)
3. DocuSign geo-location is just used to leverage the location capability of HTML5 enabled browsers but the signers IP address is recorded either way. It has no impact on which data center the traffic comes from. It is also included in the embedded signing process. It can be disabled on a per brand basis in the Signing Resource File setting the node DocuSign_DisableLocationAwareness to true.