# How do you disable the DocuSign browser-based geo-location popup dialog

Tags: javascript, html, docusignapi

I would like to disable the geo-location browser popup dialog generated by our implementation of the DocuSign iFrame since it records the user's IP address as a location arker regardless of the user's response to the dialog. I cannot seem to figure out how to set this request to False.

Can anyone assist?

Tangentially-related thread:
[Trouble-shooting slow-loading documents from DocuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883821/trouble-shooting-slow-loading-documents-from-docusign/31957036#31957036)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually changed in the Branding Signing Resource File. Set the DocuSign_DisableLocationAwareness node to true (disabled). The default value is false (enabled).

The Signing Resource File Guide can be found [here](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-signing-resource-file-information.pdf).

EDIT: Just noticed the question you linked that I answered back in August. You must login to the DocuSign WebApp and from Preferences --> Branding --> Resource Files download the signing resource file, modify the XML to set the node to True and then reupload on that same page. Disabling Geolocation is not something that can be done on a per envelope basis (or via the API) as it is an account wide change.

Comment: Note that you need to switch to "Classic DocuSign" UI to access the features listed in this answer.  To switch go to Preferences -> Switch to Classic.